# Need clarifications on cookies and sessions

Tags: jsp, session, servlets

I am confused with cookies and using session in servlets in jsp's and servlets. I have 3 questions.
1. I am creating a session for a user in my servlet A and then putting a few values in the session object. Then if the user accesses another servlet B in the same domain, will the servlet be able to read the values. Will the same session object be available to the servlet B.?
2. If I have 5 tabs open containg the different jsp pages of the same server(or domain). Will the method sessio.lastAccessed() for all the 5 tabs return the same value?
3. Can expiry be set for a session object? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. yes, they will share the session
2. yes, I believe tabs always share a session, but multiple windows will depend on the browser -- you can have multiple instances of IE (separate windows), for example, and they won't.
3. yes, by setting session-config/session-timeout in web.xml (number of minutes, see below)

   <session-config>
       <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
   </session-config>

also, to set the session timeout programmatically, use this method:

```
HttpSession session
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(int interval)
```

where interval is measured in seconds.

Comment: Can't the session expiry be set in the servlet when it is created like it is done for cookies?

Comment: Not sure precisely what you mean, but there is surely more than one way to do it.

Comment: I mean that in cookies you can set the max age. Can you do something like that sor session?

Comment: Do you mean the whole session or one session attribute? I believe the whole session will expire together as a unit.

Comment: yes the whole sesion will expire together but can the expiry time be set in a servlet when the session is created, on first access to the servlet?

Comment: you can call `setMaxInactiveInterval(int interval)` where interval is in seconds -- http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval(int)